# Using Docker image in containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I have a Docker image and I imported it to containerd by executing
`docker save -o flaskapp.tar flaskapp:v1`

Now I imported it to containerd using below
`ctr images import flaskapp.tar`

After this `ctr images list` showing the required image

```
root@test:/home/test/demo-flask-app# ctr images ls
REF                           TYPE                                                 DIGEST                                                                  SIZE      PLATFORMS   LABELS
docker.io/library/flaskapp:v1 application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:eecf6ae069cb7ec4bc6126a0fbe5e7ef1b136ac42e3466ee7e029342630f5321 530.4 MiB linux/amd64 -
root@test:/home/test/demo-flask-app#
```

Deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-proj-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: flask-proj
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-proj
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-proj
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-proj
        image: docker.io/library/flaskapp:v1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
```

When I use `docker.io/library/flaskapp:v1` in my k8s deployment YAML, k8s is not able to pull the image. What is wrong here?

Comment: Please add your deployment `yaml` file

Comment: Does your image exist on `docker.io`. Did you psuh your image to said image repo with the `docker push ` command?

Answer (score 0):

`containerd` containers are namespaced and they run in `k8s.io` namespace for Kubernetes. So the image needs to be present in `k8s.io` containerd namespace for this to work. You can try following to confirm:

```
$ ctr -n k8s.io images ls
# if image is not found, import it
$ ctr -n k8s.io images import flaskapp.tar
```

If you don't like to pass the namespace with every command, you can override it with `CONTAINERD_NAMESPACE`:

```
export CONTAINERD_NAMESPACE=k8s.io
```